# where is Apple's reference documentation

Tags: macos

In general, where would one find comprehensive documentation for Apple's software that comes with MacOS? The help menu option is almost always useless.  This stuff has to be documented somewhere.  Where is it?

Below a couple of examples.  Please, while I would love to know the answers to the questions posed in the examples, let's not get distracted with them. My question is IN GENERAL where would I find this kind of info.

[image]

How can I find out exactly what Spin Reports in the Console.app are?  Does anyone find this explanation to provide insight into what functionality Spin Reports UI feature offers?  To me, absolutely not.

[image]

In airport utility, how do I find out what exactly Router Mode pulldown menu controls?  The unhelpful help is organized as tutorials to achieve specific tasks using the software. Where can I find what the acronyms stand for?  How do their meanings relate to the function of the router controlled by the UI feature?

Comment: Manufacturer provides user guides (like [Apps included on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-built-in-apps-mchl110b00b7/13.0/mac/13.0)) and not education. Education can be obtained in the university (or in other educational institution). Leisurely browsing in internet is not replacement of that. If one is interested in subject then learning helps, if learning is not an option then there is [satirical prescription](http://www.authorama.com/three-men-in-a-boat-1.html): " .... And don’t stuff up your head with things you don’t understand.”

Comment: i do have a BS in computer science and 20+ years of experience working as a software engineer.  But I don't know what "spin reports" mean.  And the documentation seems to be targeting the audience that wouldn't ever care to understand such thing.  Where would one go to investigate such thing in more technical depth ?

Comment: @Bohemian It’s right in my answer to you - with a BS in computer science and software engineer experience that manual page should tell you everything you need to know. It’s just a system wide profiler.

Comment: "But I don't know what "spin reports" mean". I believe that on first screenshot it is explained what spin report mean.

Comment: @jksoegaard, what man page are you talking about?  The screenshot of the unhelp?  Where does it say anything about profiler there?  A profile has to be initiated, and stopped.  In many cases also instrumented during compilation as it adds significant computational overhead.... If "spin reports" is profiler output, where is the explanation of profiler controls?

Comment: @Aivar Paalberg, the point is that the explanation is too vague or general to be useful.  Sure it's reports of something or other about the system.  But how can I find out specifically how do records end up there?  And how do I control what ends up there?  How can I find out that?

Comment: @Bohemian The manpage I referenced in my answer (below) - it's the manpage for "spindump". You do not need to try to explain a profiler to me.

Comment: @Bohemian There's a reason such an explanation is vague. It's a bit like the saying "if you have to ask, you'll never know". Essentially almost every user that hits that help page would be able only to save that spinreport and send it off to a supporter. Even if the help page included a full page that explains what exactly is in the spinreport, they would not have a chance in trying to understand either the explanation nor the actual contents of the file. It's really only something that software developers, system administrators, and the like, would be able to get something useful out of [...]

Comment: [...] It would have been helpful though if Apple included a link with a technical explanation for the few that could benefit from such an explanation. My experience is that such links and explanations are usually left out in order to make the system less confusing for other users. If you are technical and want those detailed descriptions, you'll have to seek out the knowledge ourself - from the manpages, Apple's developer documentation and ofcourse general textbooks.

Comment: Good question! AFAIK, the answer is that Apple doesn't actually document very much at all.

Comment: @jksoegaard Good point.  But what if I am or want to be a developer, sys admin, etc.  ? And what if I  and don't know that spin reports in Console.app is explained in the manpage for spindump shell command... How would I find that out using official apple docs (as opposed to just googling the whole internet).

Comment: @Seamus So how do learn about such things?  What are alternative authoritative sources of such info?

Comment: @Bohemian: In the past, if I had "AppleCare", I'd call them. But for several years now, I feel the quality of that resource has been diminishing rapidly. This SE is occasionally a good resource. There are a few informative blogs [for example](https://eclecticlight.co/mac-problem-solving/) that are useful. But frankly, I try to avoid using Apple's tools when I can. I like Apple's Macbook hardware, I like `Terminal.app` - most of the rest of it is a waste AFAIC.

Comment: @Bohemian If you want to be a developer, I would suggest seeking out education (either traditional education or online-based). If you already are an Apple developer, I'm pretty sure most wouldn't look at the Activity Monitor help page and think "what in the world is that?". Spin reports are a part of the standard testing framework in Xcode, and is something that is regularly mentioned in release notes, etc. when you get new developer tool updates. There would be plenty of opportunities to "discover" that. As an Apple developer, you also have access to the developer documentation, where [...]

Comment: [...] you could lookup terms you aren't familiar with. There's also a forum for developers to ask for help from your peers - and you have the option of emailing Apple's developer support if there's something you really cannot solve. Apart from that, I don't see why you wouldn't want to "Google something". That's a really helpful tool no matter if you are developing for macOS, Windows, Linux or other platforms.

Comment: @jksoegaard You're proposing that I google "spin report"?  And spend a full day sifting through irrelevant garbage?  The point of this question was to avoid doing this.

Comment: @Bohemian If you're using a full day on that, I suggest using some time to learn how to use Google more efficiently.

Comment: @jksoegaard, ok.  And I suggest you go back to 7th grade English and learn about hyperboles and stuff.  I'm trying to figure out how to get canonical documentation from Apple.

Comment: I'll suggest not deliberately insulting those that are actually trying to help you for no benefit of their own.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such place that gathers comprehensive documentation for all of Apple's software for each searching.

In general, when Apple's help menu is lacking, it can be a good idea to simply use Google or DuckDuckGo and limit the search to apple.com, in order to find documentation from Apple.

In terms of your specific questions, you can find more information about spin reports by opening up Terminal.app on your Mac and run the command: `man spindump`. It is a developer-oriented feature, and they're generally documented on Apple's developer site.

Regarding AirPort Utility and the "Router Mode" setting - those are generic networking terms that applies to all sorts of computers and networks - not just Apple. You can read up on those in basic network literature, by searching for information on Google or on Youtube for example.